# Java Generic TreeSet

Tags: java, generics, treeset

Hi I have problem with creating a generic TreeSet with its Iterator. I want to use it to three different kind of Types.

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please add some pseudocode to help illustrate what you want.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a `TreeSet` which contains objects of type `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` you'd have to use

```
TreeSet<MostSpecificSupertypeOfABC>
```

If if there's no suitable type to use, you could create one as I have described in an answer to the question below:

- [How would you create an array list with mixed booleans and chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653282/how-would-you-create-an-array-list-with-mixed-booleans-and-chars/9653302#9653302)

Comment: What I'm trying is that, I have 3 TreeSets each with different type and I want to create a new generic TreeSet inside a method and passing those TreeSets to the method and create a generic Iterator and work on it.

Comment: public void method(TreeSet<?> set) { if(set.equals("SetA")) Iterator<SetA> iter = SetA.iterator(); else if(set.equals("SetB")) Iterator<SetB> iter = SetB.iterator(); else if(set.equals("SetC")) Iterator<SetC> iter = SetC.iterator();    while(iter.hasNext())  iter.next().getName();}   getName is inside each of the three TreeSet

Comment: I refrained from writing an answer when you first posted your question because I didn't understand what you want to do. After seeing this code in your comment, I still do not understand what you want to do. Can you explain once more, in detail, what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you simply trying to add all elements from `SetA`, `SetB` and `SetC` to a new `Set`?

Comment: I'm reading the name of the treesets from a file and I have to check each time which treeset its, after finding its name I have to work on it.